# Did Jesse do the right thing?

Tags: analysis, breaking-bad

This question keeps bugging me! Walt and Jesse both lost everything in *Breaking Bad* when Jesse decided to help Hank. If he solved his dispute with Walter by himself he would not have been tortured, Hank would not have got killed and possibly Walter would have passed away rich and happy on his bed surrounded by his children.

The only thing that makes me think otherwise is that Jesse has helped the law by betraying Walt but I highly doubt this was his motive, he just had a personal vendetta against Walt even when the latter loved him like a son.

Comment: What is the actual question you are asking here? Did Jesse do the right thing? From which perspective? If you are just asking if he did the right thing from our own moral judgment, I'm afraid the question might be entirely opinion-based. *He* certainly thought he did the right thing, but if that was ultimately the right thing for the sake of the world and everyone seems unanswerable. You might be able to improve the question, though, by concentrating on *why* Jesse did what he did and what personal motivation drove him to do so.

Comment: I got the impression that Jesse didn't **decide** to help Hank. Rather, he believes he has no choice. Jesse believes Walt wants to kill him. Therefore the only way to survive is for the police to either catch or kill Walt.

Comment: ["I think that otherwise, Jesse has helped the law by betraying Walt."] You need to preface the title with, *In the eyes of the law*, or it's still POB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short: **YES**.

Let me begin saying that one of the best things of Breaking Bad are characters, their stories and their evolution through the story. Jesse started to cook for the money, for living. He never thought himself as someone with the capacities to do anything else than sell drugs, this is also why he started using. After the death of Jane and the rehab, he says he understood and accepted what he is: the bad guy. This is not true, because later on he shows empathy, humanity and guilt for what he does:

- he doesn't want to sell or let Andrea using;
- he reveals that he is attending meetings just to sell drugs (although he was never able do to so);
- he kills Gale, but just because he had to choose between killing him and let Walt die.

Jesse is a bad guy, because he sells meth for living, but he does not become ruthless like Walt. And he understand that the only one who can stop Walt, is him.

Yes, there are heavy consequences for his actions, but I believe he did the right thing.

Comment: what do you mean the only one who can stop walt is jesse? when jesse agreed to help hank, walt already cut all ties and was entirely out of the game